# View the source code of a website built with React

Tags: reactjs

Is there anyway to view the react source code of websites built with React?

If you inspect the source code of a react page you will only see the root div. Is there a way to see the actual components?

Answer (score 12):

You can use React Developer Tools browser [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/). This will allow you to see the Component Tree of any React application. Also, you can inspect props and state of each component with it. But still, you won't be able to see the source code of Component after a production build.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 tools which might help .
One is already mentioned in the answer by @tharaka
The other tool is [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) for state management .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the existence of source map files to see the actual source code. (***otherwise, you just can read the Transpiled/Vague source code***)

quoted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map):

> A source map is a file that maps from the transformed source to the
> original source, enabling the browser to reconstruct the original
> source and present the reconstructed original in the debugger.

In default mode, [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) will create a source map for each generated js file, so by using it you can read the actual source code in the `developer tools`.

NOTE: there is a tool called [unwebpack-sourcemap](https://github.com/rarecoil/unwebpack-sourcemap) to recovering the uncompiled TypeScript sources, JSX, and more from Webpack sourcemaps which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Developer Tools browser extension. This will allow you to see the Component Tree of any React application. Also, you can inspect props and the state of each component with it. But still, you won't be able to see the source code of the Component after a production build